# Ĉi tie or ĉi-tie? Why do people sometimes hyphenate ĉi tie?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’ve seen "ĉi tie", "tie ĉi", "tie-ĉi", "ĉi-tie". I’m pretty sure that any hyphenation is wrong, but I can’t find the sources for this. Maybe someone can clarify? Is “ĉi" ever hyphenated?

Answer (score 9):

There's a [part in PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-lgm) about this topic:

> *Ĉi* estas aparta vorto. Ne skribu: **ĉi-tiu**, **tiu-ĉi**, **ĉi-tie**, **tie-ĉi**, **ĉio-ĉi** k.t.p. Skribu: *ĉi tiu*, *tiu ĉi*, *ĉi tie*, *tie ĉi*, *ĉio ĉi* k.t.p. Se oni skribus **tiu-ĉi**, **tie-ĉi**, **ĉio-ĉi**, oni devus akcenti: **ti**ú**-ĉi**, **ti**é**-ĉi**, **ĉi**ó**-ĉi**, laŭ la [akcentoregulo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-la2), sed tiel neniu elparolas. Oni do ankaŭ ne skribu tiel. Sed oni povas el tiaj esprimoj fari [aliajn kunmetaĵojn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-h6f), kaj tiam oni ja kunskribu, kaj ofte oni tiam uzas dividostrekon post *ĉi*.

Translation:

> *Ĉi* is a separate word. Don't write **ĉi-tiu**, **tiu-ĉi**, **ĉi-tie**, **tie-ĉi**, **ĉio-ĉi** etc. Write: *ĉi tiu*, *tiu ĉi*, *ĉi tie*, *tie ĉi*, *ĉio ĉi* etc. If one would write **tiu-ĉi**, **tie-ĉi**, **ĉio-ĉi**, one should stress: **ti**ú**-ĉi**, **ti**é**-ĉi**, **ĉi**ó**-ĉi**, according to the [stress rule](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-la2), but no one pronounces like that. So one should also not write like that. But one can create [other compounds](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-h6f) from such expressions, and then one should compound, and one often uses a hyphen after *ĉi* in that case.

So simplified: you should never use a hyphen when it's part of a correlative ("ĉi tie", "tiu ĉi", "ĉi tio", etc.), but you should use a hyphen if it's part of a compound word ("ĉi-tieaj", "ĉi-sube", "ĉi-flanka", etc.).

Comment: PMEG only says that "often" oni uzas streketon por _ĉitiea_. That doesn't mean you should actually use it.

Answer (score 5):

"Ĉi" kun korelativoj ĉiam estas sen streketo. Sed ofte oni ankaŭ uzas ĉi kun aliaj vortoj, kaj tiam kutime oni uzas streketon, ekzemple "ĉi-semajnfine". Kompreneble kelkaj homoj konfuziĝas pro ĉi tio kaj ankaŭ aplikas tiun streketon al korelativoj, kio malĝustas.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cause of the confusion is that we have two *ĉi* words or wordparts with totally different meanings. At least it was to me a source of confusion.

### la tabelvorta ĉi- ĝeneraligas

The correlatives beginning with *ĉi-* generalise.

- *ĉio* : everything
- *ĉiu* : everyone
- …

One is not allowed to shorten correlatives (they are single words), and they are often written without a hyphen in compound words.

- *Ĉiumatene* (< *ĉiu matene*) *kiam mi ellitiĝas…* : Every morning when I get up from bed…
- *Kiukolora estas la pomo?* : What colour has the apple? / What colour is the apple?

### la primitiva adverbo ĉi precizigas

The primitive adverb *ĉi* is a separate word as stated in other replies. It can only appear with correlatives beginning with *ti-*.

- *ĉi tio* : this
- *ĉi tia* : this like
- …

However these kinds of expressions are often, especially in adverbial expressions, abbreviated with a hyphen.

- *ĉi-jara* < *ĉi tiu jara* : this year(-ian)
- *ĉi-kune* < *ĉi tio kune* : with this, here attached

Sometimes one leaves the hyphen out.

- *Ĉimatene* (< *ĉi-matene* < *ĉi tiu matene*) *kiam mi ellitiĝis…*  : When I got up from the bed this morning…

Note the one letter difference between *ĉiumatene* and *ĉimatene*. In speech you can hear the difference, but IMHO in text it's better to use a hyphen in the latter case to make the difference clear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever **need** to hyphenate it. You **could** if you wanted to. But even Zamenhof used them without hyphen when they are part of a word/bigger unit (that's when PMEG says they are often used):

> Ĉu vi ne estas ĉitieulo!

(La Gimnazio, Zamenhof)

> ...kiel memorigaĵon pri mia ĉitiea vizito

(Fabeloj de Andersen 4, Zamenhof)

And he had a pretty strong opinion on the use of hypens when it was just about ĉi and the noun (PMEG also says so):

> La uzado de streketo inter la montra vorto kaj “ĉi” (t.e. skribado “tiu-ĉi” aŭ “ĉitiu” anstataŭ “tiu ĉi” aŭ “ĉi tiu”) ŝajnas al mi nur simpla erara kutimo, kiun nenio pravigas.

(Lingvaj respondoj, Zamenhof)

All in all, you are safer not ever using them than having to check the gramatical situation you are in and besides the examples above, you can also always write *ĉi posttagmeze*, *ĉi momente*, ktp.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that to a lot of people "ci-tio/tio-ĉi" and "ĉi-tie/tie-ĉi" are single words.

the hyphen is necessary in words like "ĉi-pere" and "ĉi-semajne",  but wrong in "ĉitiea"